# Space i cant get rid off

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a script that works great

```
<form name="contactform" method="POST" action="mssql.php">
<textarea name="user" cols="20" rows="6"></textarea>
<textarea name="pass" cols="20" rows="6"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<?php

$user = $_POST['user'];
$lines = explode("\n", $user);
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
$lines1 = explode("\n", $pass);

echo "Paste into command line to add user and passwords<br><br>";
echo "=======================================<br><br>";

foreach (array_combine($lines, $lines1) as $v => $t) {
        echo "CREATE LOGIN " . $v . " WITH PASSWORD = '" . $t . "';<br>GO<br>";
}
echo "=======================================<br><br>";

?>
```

The only problem is the output:

```
Paste into command line to add user and passwords

=======================================
CREATE LOGIN user1 WITH PASSWORD = 'pass1 ';
GO
CREATE LOGIN user2 WITH PASSWORD = 'pass2';
GO
=======================================
```

Notice the space after the pass1  --> 'pass1 ';

how do i get rid of that?

Thank You

Comment: Looks to me like you might have a SQL Injection vulnerability here if you ever automatically execute the generated `CREATE LOGIN...` code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `trim()`

```
echo "CREATE LOGIN " . trim($v) . 
   " WITH PASSWORD = '" . trim($t) . "';<br>GO<br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to `trim` it like

```
foreach (array_combine($lines, $lines1) as $v => $t) {
    $t = trim($t);
    echo "CREATE LOGIN " . $v . " WITH PASSWORD = '" . $t . "';<br>GO<br>";
}
```

`trim` function returns a string with whitespace stripped from the beginning and end of string.Refer this [**LINK**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)